# How Do I Convert This Java Code to Kotlin libGDX

Tags: java, kotlin, libgdx

```
actor.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        System.out.println("Changed!");
    }
});
```

I can't figure out how to convert the ChangeEvent handler code from Java to Kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
actor.addListener(object : ChangeListener() {
        fun changed(event: ChangeEvent?, actor: Actor?) {
            println("Changed!")
        }
    })
```

Comment: @WhoCares please, accept it as an answer then

Comment: i apologies i haven't used Stackoverflow before

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [ktx actors library](https://github.com/libktx/ktx/tree/master/actors), it becomes very simple:

```
actor.onChange {
    println("Changed!")
}
```

or if you need the event for some reason:

```
actor.onChangeEvent { event ->
    println("Changed!")
}
```